# Hibernation file not matching total memory

Tags: windows-10, memory, hibernate

When it comes to the size of the hibernation file, (I have 8 Gb of RAM, 4.2/10.8 total, at the time of writing, only using around 3 Gb of it), is it supposed to match my total memory or the current usage. This is because the file size is only ~3 Gb, so will it change according to usage, predecided on start up?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When hibernate is enabled Windows will create a file on your system drive to handle the hibernation process.By default the file is 75% of your RAM amount – a computer with 4 GB of RAM would have a 3.5 GB hiberfil.sys file.

This can be be changed to any other amount between 50% – 100% – however if Windows needs more than the amount you have allocated the computer will fail to enter hiberation.

The steps below show how to change the size of the hiberfil.sys file.

Lets say your windows is using small size for the hiberfil.sys and you want to 
manually change it to 75% which is recommended.
Press windows button and type cmd
Right click on ‘Command Prompt’ and click on ‘Run as administrator’
lets say now your windows is using 40%, to change this to 75% Enter the following command and hit enter

**powercfg -h -size 75**

The hiberfil.sys file will now be changed to the new amount. Click the window using the X at the top right or type exit and hit enter on the keyboard.

Ref: [This link](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/windows-10/windows-10-how-to-reduce-hibernate-hiberfil-sys-file-size/)

Note: If you are running windows 10, better not to change it as windows is already managing this optimally.